# How to display that forms?

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I'm thinking how to display forms in that configuration:
I have 3 simple models:

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class UserProvince(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)

class UserCity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, editable=False)
```

now, each user can have several provinces added. then, he can add several cities to his each added province.
province1
    city1
    city2
    city3
province2
    city4
    city5
    city6
province3
    city7
    city8
    city9

I want to display all his provinces and under each of it, I want to display form with input to add city to it. What is the best way to do this? There's going to be unknown number of provinces.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to add the user to your context, and generate the forms required from methods of the user, province and city objects.

Add a method to the Province model to return an 'add_city' form.

Then, in the view, you can generate an 'add_province' form for the user.

In the template, you would then render the add_province form, then iterate over the users provinces, emitting the information about them and using the provinces 'add_country_form' method to generate the required forms for the countries along with iterating over the countries emitting their information.